# How can I display form with select options as horizontaly lists?

Tags: css, forms, select, optgroup

It is posible by css to display a form with select as vertical lists following code ?

```
<form action="">
<select class="selectWidth" name="size" id="size" type="text">
<optgroup label="Standard">
    <option value="800x600" >800x600</option>
    <option value="1024x768" >1024x768</option>
    <option value="1280x960" >1280x960</option>
    <option value="1280x1024" >1280x1024</option>
    <option value="1400x1050" >1400x1050</option>
    <option value="1600x1200" >1600x1200</option>
    <option value="2560x2048" >2560x2048</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="Widescreen">
    <option value="1024x600" >1024x600</option>
    <option value="1280x800" >1280x800</option>
    <option value="1366x768" >1366x768</option>
    <option value="1440x900" >1440x900</option>
    <option value="1600x900" >1600x900</option>
    <option value="1680x1050" >1680x1050</option>
    <option value="1920x1080" >1920x1080</option>
    <option value="1920x1200" >1920x1200</option>
    <option value="2560x1440" >2560x1440</option>
    <option value="2560x1600" >2560x1600</option>
 </optgroup>

 <optgroup label="Mobile">
     <option value="240x320" >240x320 (ipod)</option>
     <option value="320x480" >320x480 (iphone)</option>
     <option value="640x960" >640x960 (iphone4)</option>
     <option value="640x1136" >640x1136 (iphone5)</option>
     <option value="1024x1024" >1024x1024 (ipad)</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
</form>
```

I would like to be displayed like this:

Standard:  800x600  1024x768  1280x960 .....

Widescreen: 1024x600  1280x800 ....  2560x1600

Mobile : 240x320 320x480 640x960 ..... 1024x1024

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking....

Comment: You can use media queries why to use this much complicated method

Comment: There's no way to do this in css as long as different resolutions shall be different options. Although transformation to what you want with javascript would be rather easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Use `javascript` to convert the `select` element into a marked-up nested list; and then
2. Use `CSS` to display the nested list as 3 horizontal lists

Is this the kind of thing you mean:

```js
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[1];
var select = form.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
var groups = select.getElementsByTagName('optgroup');

var labels = [];
var subLists = [];
var parentListItems = [];
var parentListItemText = [];

var parentList = document.createElement('ul');

for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
  labels[i] = groups[i].getAttribute('label');
  parentListItems[i] = document.createElement('li');
  parentListItemText[i] = document.createTextNode(labels[i] + ': ');
  
  subLists[i] = document.createElement('ul');

  var options = groups[i].getElementsByTagName('option');

  for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
    var text = options[j].innerHTML;
    var subOption = document.createElement('li');
    var subOptionText = document.createTextNode(text);
    subLists[i].appendChild(subOption);
    subOption.appendChild(subOptionText);
  }

  parentList.appendChild(parentListItems[i]);
  parentListItems[i].appendChild(parentListItemText[i]);
  parentListItems[i].appendChild(subLists[i]);
}

form.insertBefore(parentList,select);

select.style.display = 'none';
```

```css
h2 {
color: rgba(255, 0, 0 , 1);
}

hr {
margin: 48px;
}

ul, ul li {
display: block;
}

ul, li {
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
list-style: none;
font-weight: bold;
}

li ul, li ul li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 6px;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<h2>Before:</h2>
<form action="">
<select class="selectWidth" name="size" id="size" type="text">
<optgroup label="Standard">
    <option value="800x600" >800x600</option>
    <option value="1024x768" >1024x768</option>
    <option value="1280x960" >1280x960</option>
    <option value="1280x1024" >1280x1024</option>
    <option value="1400x1050" >1400x1050</option>
    <option value="1600x1200" >1600x1200</option>
    <option value="2560x2048" >2560x2048</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="Widescreen">
    <option value="1024x600" >1024x600</option>
    <option value="1280x800" >1280x800</option>
    <option value="1366x768" >1366x768</option>
    <option value="1440x900" >1440x900</option>
    <option value="1600x900" >1600x900</option>
    <option value="1680x1050" >1680x1050</option>
    <option value="1920x1080" >1920x1080</option>
    <option value="1920x1200" >1920x1200</option>
    <option value="2560x1440" >2560x1440</option>
    <option value="2560x1600" >2560x1600</option>
 </optgroup>

 <optgroup label="Mobile">
     <option value="240x320" >240x320 (ipod)</option>
     <option value="320x480" >320x480 (iphone)</option>
     <option value="640x960" >640x960 (iphone4)</option>
     <option value="640x1136" >640x1136 (iphone5)</option>
     <option value="1024x1024" >1024x1024 (ipad)</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
</form>

<hr />

<h2>After:</h2>
<form action="">
<select class="selectWidth" name="size" id="size" type="text">
<optgroup label="Standard">
    <option value="800x600" >800x600</option>
    <option value="1024x768" >1024x768</option>
    <option value="1280x960" >1280x960</option>
    <option value="1280x1024" >1280x1024</option>
    <option value="1400x1050" >1400x1050</option>
    <option value="1600x1200" >1600x1200</option>
    <option value="2560x2048" >2560x2048</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="Widescreen">
    <option value="1024x600" >1024x600</option>
    <option value="1280x800" >1280x800</option>
    <option value="1366x768" >1366x768</option>
    <option value="1440x900" >1440x900</option>
    <option value="1600x900" >1600x900</option>
    <option value="1680x1050" >1680x1050</option>
    <option value="1920x1080" >1920x1080</option>
    <option value="1920x1200" >1920x1200</option>
    <option value="2560x1440" >2560x1440</option>
    <option value="2560x1600" >2560x1600</option>
 </optgroup>

 <optgroup label="Mobile">
     <option value="240x320" >240x320 (ipod)</option>
     <option value="320x480" >320x480 (iphone)</option>
     <option value="640x960" >640x960 (iphone4)</option>
     <option value="640x1136" >640x1136 (iphone5)</option>
     <option value="1024x1024" >1024x1024 (ipad)</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
</form>
```